# Disk provison for new vSphere enviroment

Tags: virtualization, vmware-vsphere, provisioning

I'm deploying a vsphere environment with more than 200 new vm on 20TB datastore and stuck with disk provisioning. Eager zeroed was used before, but for 100 vm it will take a lot of time and i'm thinking about lazy zeroed.

Are there any differences for vm or potential issues with lazy zeroed? Most vms are Linux.

Comment: What's the actual underlying storage?

Comment: 18 SAS 10k . We use RAID10

Comment: So it's a single host with just local DAS? Have you just considered 'thinning' them all?

Comment: it is single host environment for application testing purposes before production. And i'm not considering thin provision, but lazy zeroed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lazy zeroed provisioning just reserves the space, but doesn’t fill it with zeroes, so by first writing the allocated space on vmdk should be zeroed, what decreases the performance. The performance won’t be decreased on rewriting already existing blocks. You can use Thin Provisioning Lazy Zeroed with VMs without high IOPS requirements and Eager Zeroed with high performing.

More about the provisioning  - https://www.vmwareblog.org/vmware-esxi-disk-provision-work-difference-one-better/

Comment: Thanks! what performance difference should i expect?

Comment: Initial write performance will be definitely much slower. I suggest create two test VMs (or one VM with two attached disks) – one with lazy zeroed and the second eager zeroed. After that just run benchmarking like fio or diskspd.